# Plot 3 D cube around interest point in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to plot 3D cube of size 2x2x5 (x,y,z) around an interest point to get the nearest points to it and inside the cube. The interest point may be at the center of cube.

How can I get the nearest points to the interest point?

Answer (score 0):

There are several techniques for drawing cubes [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/235581). You will need to choose one that lets you specify size and origin. The sizes will be 2,2,5, and the origin will be the coordinates of the interest point.